# delete operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]
    As the code under if I use the delete operator and delete the me.name
    pointer that is referencing to first pointer. and then console the 
    name.first its coming as undefined but its should not as name has allocated
    a seperated memory space..pls explain?

```
<script>
    var me = {
        name : {
            first: 'atul'
            } 
        },
        name = me.name;

    delete me.name;

    name.first // should fetch 'atul' but it's coming undefined why?
</script>
```

Comment: You did not close the curly braces properly.

Comment: edited thanks..pls explain further

Comment: `name` belonged to me. when you delete it, nothing is pointing to it and it gets garage collected

Comment: It is working fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/u6azsL7q/2/

Comment: Your issue is `name`. It's a reserved property. Change it to `fullName = me.name` and it will continue to exist

Comment: yes but how's its working in fiddle then as done by rajaprabhu